# Refresh owl-carousel in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I have some issues with the owl carousel regarding dynamic changes, such as amount of slides etc. - in other words, the carousel tempts to break after some changes.

My approach was to reload/refresh the carousel - but how?

I found online that you have to refresh it by class:

```
$owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

But how do I translate this to Angular/Typescipt?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel. It's designed to work with Angular. It successfully works event in the last 8th version of Angular

Comment: @SergeyMell I do, but still, how do I refresh the carousel even with this library?

Answer (score 2):

So, as long as you are using `ngx-owl-carousel` (following your comment) your implementation could look as follows.

```
// component template

<owl-carousel [items]="images" #owlElement>
     <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of images;let i = index">
         <div class="thumbnail-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url('abc.jpg')no-repeat scroll center center / 80px 80px'}"></div>
     </div>
 </owl-carousel>
```

Please, pay attention to `owlElement` template variable

Then if you want to handle or trigger some actions you can refer to this element

```
// Component class

import {OwlCarousel} from 'ngx-owl-carousel';

export class HomeComponent {

@ViewChild('owlElement') owlElement: OwlCarousel

   refresh() {
     this.owlElement.refresh()
   }
}
```

You can call whatever events you want from [original documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) using method trigger (`trigger(action: string, options?: any[])`).

Comment: This advice was exactly what I needed.  It gives you access to any public method defined in the ngx-owl-carousel (actually ngx-owl-carousel-o is more recent and has more features) underlying carousel.component.ts.  Using the full carousel code project, you can go further by defining additional public methods.

Comment: Sergey. it is not working.. it says "refresh is not a function"

Comment: Are you sure you're using `ngx-owl-carousel` not `ngx-owl-carousel-o`? They could be different. Since the ngx-owl-carousel was not updated for 4 years the method should still work. Could you share some demo so I could check?

Comment: yes im using ngx-owl-carousel-o.. i have button Next. while click the next button, move the slider to next using this.owlElement.next(). if next == 3, im loading the more data from http that time slider move from 1 to 4

Comment: As you can see, my answer is valid for `ngx-owl-carousel`, not for `ngx-owl-carousel-o` library. You can create a separate SO question and would be great if you share some code example there - I would be glad to help

Comment: yes your answer is correct. any idea to achieve this in ngx-owl-carousel-o because ngx-owl-carousel needs jquery.