# Trigger refresh for owl carousel in angular in the package ngx-owl-carousel-o

Tags: javascript, angular, owl-carousel-2

I want my owl carousel to refresh with the renewed responsive options. In jquery this can be done by using: 
`$owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');`
as mentioned here: [Refresh owl-carousel in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050522/refresh-owl-carousel-in-angular) (but for a different plugin that uses jquery as a dependency).

In the api, there's a mention of `refreshClass` but no mention of triggering a refresh of the instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add your ViewChild:

```
   @ViewChild('carousel', { static: true }) carousel: CarouselComponent;
```

Retrieve you service;

```
   const anyService = this.carousel as any;
   const carouselService = anyService.carouselService as CarouselService;

    carouselService.refresh();
    carouselService.update();
```

Comment: after calling refresh my carousel disappear

Answer (score 1):

Based on UberGeoff suggestion, I have found this solution.

```
@ViewChild('owlCar', { static: true }) owlCar: CarouselComponent;

.
.

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    let anyService = this.owlCar as any;
    let carouselService = anyService.carouselService as CarouselService;  
    carouselService.onResize(event.target.innerWidth);
}
```

is not an elegant solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for an answer to this as well. My idea was to access the element using @Viewchild, then the CarouselService. By the way, how it did went on your end? @Anon

Comment: I ended up not using the carousel but keen to find a solution for the future use.

Comment: So what alternative did you use? I'll skip working on this for now but will be back on a few weeks to looking a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of refreshing, do not assign the values inside the owl options and assign them inside hostlistener like this. It works fine now.
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])

checkScreenSize(event?) {

```
this.isDesktop = window.innerWidth >= 768 ? true : false;
if (this.isDesktop) {
  this.customOptions.touchDrag = false;
  this.customOptions.mouseDrag = false;
}
else {
  this.customOptions.touchDrag = true;
  this.customOptions.mouseDrag = true;
}
```

}

customOptions: OwlOptions = {
margin: 10,
stagePadding: 10,
loop: false,
dots: false,
navSpeed: 600,
navText: ["", ""],
nav: true,
responsive: {
0: {
items: 4
}
}
}