# how to change the order of the item inside the slider base on direction(rtl, ltr) for owl carousel slider angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, owl-carousel

I'm trying to change the direction of the [owl-carousel-o angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o) slider depending on the selected language.

I have set `rtl: true` in the owl-carousel config when initiating it. When the user changes the language, I want to change the `rtl` to `false`, but I have to reload the carousel so it takes the update.

I have tried to reload the carousel using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63466333/12614207):

```js
@ViewChild('carousel', { static: true }) carousel: CarouselComponent;

const anyService = this.carousel as any;
const carouselService = anyService.carouselService as CarouselService;
// Here I change the rtl value to false
carouselService.refresh();
carouselService.update();
```

But the carousel stays in `rtl` mode even when I switch the language to `ltr` mode.

Any ideas on solving the problem?

This is how I want to display the slider:

Arabic(rtl):

[image]

English(ltr):

[image]

The `config.ts` file:

```
const sliderConfig = {
  loop: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  rtl: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    300: {
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    500: {
      items: 2,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    640: {
      items: 2,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    700: {
      items: 3,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    900: {
      items: 3,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1200: {
      items: 5,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1400: {
      items: 5,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1600: {
      items: 6,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1920: {
      items: 7,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
  },
};
```

---

This is how I change the direction of the website when the user switches the language. The `.rtl` or `.ltr` is added to the html body.

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}
.ltr {
  direction: ltr !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: FYI: You can also you `text-align: start` which automatically switches between `left` or `right` based on the set direction. Be aware that [support isn't optimal](https://caniuse.com/?search=logical%20properties) yet. Checkout [logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties) for more info

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the Rtl value to variable first of all (before the initialization carousel). Like so:

```
@ViewChild('carousel', { static: true }) carousel: CarouselComponent;

const anyService = this.carousel as any;
const carouselService = anyService.carouselService as CarouselService;
// Here I change the rtl value to false
var rtlBoolen = false; //or true if rtl off
carouselService.refresh();
carouselService.update();
```

and after that init the carousel:

```
const sliderConfig = {
  loop: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  rtl: rtlBoolen, // here use the variable defined before
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    300: {
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    500: {
      items: 2,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    640: {
      items: 2,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    700: {
      items: 3,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    900: {
      items: 3,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1200: {
      items: 5,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1400: {
      items: 5,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1600: {
      items: 6,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
    1920: {
      items: 7,
      stagePadding: 50,
    },
  },
};
```